# How to get access of web token after log in method

Tags: angular, asynchronous, jwt, observable, angular-http-interceptors

I am creating authentication for logging into my application using JWT. my login method returns the token that is generated by my server application. After that the token is set into local storage. I want to add the token to the header so I have created a token-interceptor service to accomplish this. However, When writing the bearer token I notice that it is null. I am trying to access the token AFTER the login and setting of the token in local storage has completed.

I've read a bunch questions similar to my own but cannot seem to figure it out.
I've tried using Promises, timeouts(which I don't think is the best solution).
I've tried using if statements to see if a user is logged in but that only works on the second attempt to login and not the first. I know that the login method is firing before the intercept method and so that is why its null so then I've been trying to use an observable to wait until the token is set to add it to the header but I'm not really sure when, where, or how it should be happening. All of this is new to me btw. I've tried making both set and get methods of token Observables but I'm probably not doing that correctly. I'm not expert at writing Observables yet.  I'm just in need of some guidance as to how to get the token with the use of Observables if that's even the best option.

login.component.ts

```
loginUser(){
  this.authenticateService.loginUser(this.loginUserData)
  .subscribe(
            res => {
                this.authenticateService.setToken(res.token)
                this.router.navigate(['/profile'])
            },
            err => console.log('ERROR: '+err)
            )
  }
```

auth.service.ts

```
  //function to login user and athenticate user
  loginUser(user){
    return this.http.post<any>('/api/login',user)
  }

  //check if token exist in browser, the user is logged in
  isLoggedIn(){
    return (!!localStorage.getItem('token') && !localStorage.getItem('token') === null)

  }

setToken(token){
    localStorage.setItem('token', token)
}
 getToken(){ 
    return localStorage.getItem('token')

 }
```

token-interceptor.service.ts

```
intercept (req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>>{

        const authToken = this.authService.getToken()
        console.log('token',authToken)
        if(authToken != null){
            const authReq = req.clone({
            headers: req.headers.set('Authorization','Bearer ' + authToken)
            });

            return next.handle(authReq);
        }else{
            return next.handle(req);
        }

}
```

I expect the output of the bearer token to not be null and actually have the token. The intercept method doesn't work right now because of the subscribe thing I have going on but I'm just not sure how to go about it.

Comment: authService.setToken is a function, not an observable. You can't subscribe to a function. Just remove the line `this.authService.setToken.subscribe(`, which makes no sense.

Comment: I've tried making it an observable too, to the best of my knowledge at least and it didn't work.

Comment: Again, you don't need any observable. getToken() returns the token, synchronously. So just get the token. Then clone the request, the pass the cloned request to next.handle().

Comment: the getToken method is returning null because Its firing before the login method even completes and that when its set so that's my main issue. to wait for login to complete

Comment: Well, your interceptor intercepts **all** the HTTP requests. Including the one you use to login, and thus get the token in the first place. Just don't clone the request if the token is null.

Comment: ohhhh, okay. Didn't quite understand the interceptor part. That helps. thank you

Comment: So then How would I retrieve the token in the intercept method from the server, if the token is generated after the login post request WHICH would be interrupted by the interceptor

Comment: The intercept method is called every time you send a request. So it will be first called when you login. The interceptor won't do anything then, since there is no token in local storage yet. When the login succeeds, the login component stores the token in local storage. For every subsequent request, the interceptor will read the token in local storage, find it, and add it as a header to the request. An interceptor doesn't **interrupt** the request. It **intercepts** the request to modify it before it's sent to the server.